# Wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having an error by trying to create a relational object ingredient_measure, this is my controller:

```
 module Api
  module V1
    class IngredientMeasuresController < ApplicationController

    def index
      render json: IngredientMeasure.all
    end

    def create
      ingredient_measure = IngredientMeasure.new(params[:ingredient_id, :measure_id])
      if ingredient_measure.save
        render json: ingredient_measure
      else
        render json: {status: 500, err: 'Ingredient measure could not be created'}
      end
    end
    private

    def ingredient_measure_params
      params.require(:ingredient_measure).permit(:ingredient_id, :measure_id)
     end
   end
 end
end
```

and when I POST something like this

```
{       
    "measure_id" : 3,
    "ingredient_id":3
}
```

it gives me the `wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)` error, even though my model has those two fields since I can create them by the rails console but not with the controller, and if I use

`ingredient_measure = IngredientMeasure.new(ingredient_measure_params)`

at line 10 I get the `param is missing or the value is empty: ingredient_measure`error

this is my model in the schema

```
create_table "ingredient_measures", force: :cascade do |t|
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.bigint "ingredient_id"
t.bigint "measure_id"
t.index ["ingredient_id"], name: "index_ingredient_measures_on_ingredient_id"
t.index ["measure_id"], name: "index_ingredient_measures_on_measure_id"
end
```

Comment: try with `IngredientMeasure.new(ingredient_measure_params)` + use `fetch` instead of `require` for your permit params: `params.fetch(:ingredient_measure, {}).permit(:ingredient_id, :measure_id)`

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way you pass the params into the `ActiveRecord` model. 
It should be:

```
ingredient_measure = IngredientMeasure.new(ingredient_measure_params)
```

The exact reason you get this error is you try to call `[]` method on hash-like structure returned by `params` with two arguments (`[:ingredient_id, :measure_id]`), which obviously doesn't make sense. If you ever encounter `[]` operator, it's usually safe to presume it takes only one argument.

Comment: when I do it like this, it throws me `ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: ingredient_measure`

Answer (score -1):

I had unchecked the option Content-type application/json in postman from where i was posting the data